# Function is not returning the right value in C

Tags: c, function, return-value

I'm trying to make a program that finds the root of an equation. Everything about my program works just fine, except for the equation itself: it keeps returning wrong values (1, infinity, 0, ...).

This is the function I'm evaluating:

```
double f(x) {
    return exp(-x)-sin(M_PI*x/2.);
}
```

For example, f(.3) should be .287, but it returns 1.000. Weird thing is, I tried the exact same code on another computer a while ago and it worked just fine.

Comment: what is the function signature? `double f(x)` is ill formed.

Comment: @Elazar: As of C90, it's not ill formed; it's an old style (pre-ANSI) definition, with the type of `x` defaulting to `int`. As of C99, the "implicit `int`" rule was dropped, and it's a constraint violation, requiring a diagnostic.

Comment: @KeithThompson thanks. you can see from my answer that I know about the default-to-int - or could have guessed that, since *everything* defaults to `int`, for some reason... I assume `f(x){ }` is a well-formed function that gets an `int` and returns an `int`, too :P . I will be happy to know what were K&R thinking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
double f(x) {
    return exp(-x)-sin(M_PI*x/2.);
}
```

The type for x is not declared, so it defaults to `int`.

You pass `.3`, so it coerced to `int` and become 0.

```
exp(-0)-sin(M_PI*0/2.) == exp(0)-sin(0) == 1.0-0 == 1.0
```

Please find yourself a better compiler, and turn on warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should cast your variable. That usually happens to me with divisions.

Answer (score 0):

```
double f(double x) {
 ......
}
```

Comment: Nah, not to worry.  Happens to everybody.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double f(double x) {
    return exp(-x)-sin(M_PI*x/2.);
}

int main(void){
    printf(".3 = %f",f(.3));
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

results:
'.3 = 0.286828'